# I have a css modal which displays a video. The video plays when the blank area where it will be displayed is clicked

Tags: css, html, modalpopup

I've tried a number of solutions but with no success.

Here is a [simplified page demonstrating the problem](http://meanroy.com/modaltry/modal.html).

Comment: I've tried changing z-index: to various values with no effect. If you right click in the center under the text you can start, stop, etc. I do find that if I hide the controls (right click Hide Controls) this doesn't happen.

Comment: show the code please

Comment: trying to put together a simpler example now

Comment: here is a jsfiddle which illustrates the problem. <http://jsfiddle.net/meanroy/s8gt8Lk5/>

Comment: oops!  http://jsfiddle.net/meanroy/s8gt8Lk5/1/  click on the blank area and the video plays but is not visible - right click shows the controls.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

I found the solution after finding a similar problem with a page using html5 columns. The modals would work in the first column but not in the second. I found that the modal static position overlapped the position of the link-image in the second column though it was not visible.

In the original problem I changed the css from:

```
   #modal1{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -20%;
    padding: 20px;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 40%;
    top: 100px;
    left: 50%;

}

#modal1:target {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

To this:

```
#modal1{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -20%;
    padding: 20px;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 40%;
    top: 100px;
    left: -1000px;

}

#modal1:target{
   position: absolute;
   margin-left: -20%;
   padding: 20px;
   opacity: 1;
   width: 40%;
   top: 100px;
   left: 50%;
```

}

Now the modal static position is well off the page and is no longer where it can be clicked.

I realize this was a noobie mess-up but I finally got it.

Roy